# Specialization of member function of class template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a `Base` class which I use as a Tree. From this Base class I derived a template `Container` class which should be able to hold various types. I would like to give the Container class a `toString` function, which converts its values and the values of all of its children to a string. A `Container<A>` can have a child of a different type `Container<B>`.

I don't know how to do this. Below is my code.

```
// File base.h:
class Base {
    public:
    virtual string toString();
    protected:
        vector<Base *> _children
}

// File base.cpp:
string Base::toString() {
    string a="something"
    return a;
}
```

Then I have a templated derived class:

```
// File container.h:
template<class T>
class Container: public Base {
    public:
        string toString() override;
    private:
        T _data;
}
```

I would like to specialize the toString function, so it can deal with
different types:

```
File container.cpp:
template <class T>
string Container<T>::toString() {
    string valueString = "not sure how to handle this type";
    for(int i=0;i<_children.size;i++) {
        valueString+=" "+_children[i]->toString();
    }
    return valueString;
}
template <>
string Container<int>::toString() {
    string valueString = std::to_string(_data);
    for(int i=0;i<_children.size;i++) {
        valueString+=" "+_children[i]->toString();
    }
    return valueString;
}
```

I gave the `Base` class also a `toString` function, as I don't know how I would cast the `_children` to an unspecified Container class so I can access its `toString` function.

If I use the above approach, I get an error at linking:

```
undefined reference to Container<void*>::toString()
undefined reference to Container<bool*>::toString()
```

and for all the other types I ever used. However, I would like to avoid specializing all possible types.

Edit:
As it has been suggested to move the content of container.cpp to the header file: If I do this, I get errors like this:

```
Multiple definition of Container<int>::toString().
First defined here
```

It seems basically that whereever I include `Container.h` I get such a multiple definition. This although I have a

```
#ifndef CONTAINER
#define CONTAINER
```

include guard?

Comment: your derived class is not inheriting from `Base`. Shouldn't it be `class Container:public Base`

Comment: You cannot put a template implementation (be it function template or class template) in a `.cpp` file and use it somewhere else!

Comment: Yes, it should be Container::public Base, thank you, but that was not the problem

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, if I simply move the implementation in container.cpp to the end of Container.h I get errors of the kind "multiple definition of Container<int>toString" first defined here..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ template only compiles when substituted.

In your situation, `Container<T>::toString` are defined in side `container.cpp`, but no substituted, so they won't be compiled.

When you reference to `Container<T>::toString` somewhere, the definition of the function is not visible to the compile unit, the compile will generate a relocation slot, hoping the definition will be find at link stage. But the function is never defined anywhere, so you got link error.

Solution: put the function definition to header file.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) are some more detailed explanation.

Comment: @maxwell add `inline` or put the definition inside class.